# A map that I develop for recently lost functionality

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm a web developer for my university, currently working on our map. The site can be found [here](http://bit.ly/TOyCVq). Under each heading appear the pushpins when the heading is clicked, and when pushpins are clicked on (either on the map or in the sidebar) an infowindow should pop up with a brief snippet about the location, usually with a photo alongside it. Unfortunately, over the last two months, the infowindows all stopped displaying. I've tried making sure our jquery is up-to-date, and run through the custom javascript we made to see if there have been any significant changes (best I can tell, there haven't). I'm wondering if there have been any recent updates to the Google Maps API that could have broken that. I'm stepping through the script trying to identify potential problem areas, but coming up dry. Any ideas?

(edit) I'll post the relevant code to the infowindows, otherwise it'd just be a headache for everyone.

```
for (var i in data.d.Buildings) {
    var color = categories[4].Color.substring(1);
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.d.Buildings[i].Latitude, data.d.Buildings[i].Longitude);
    var image = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + data.d.Buildings[i].LegendKey + '|' + color + '|ffffff';
    categoryItems['search'][i].marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        pushpinInfo: data.d.Buildings[i]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(categoryItems['search'][i].marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.content = '<div class="bubble"><h3>' + this.pushpinInfo.Name + '</h3>' + (this.pushpinInfo.ImageUrl != null ? '<img src="' + this.pushpinInfo.ImageUrl + '" alt="' + this.pushpinInfo.Acronym + '" />' : '') + this.pushpinInfo.Description + '</div>';
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

    addPushpinToMenu(categoryItems['search'][i], 'search', image);
    count++;
}
```

---

```
    if (data.d.ParkingLots[i].Name != null && data.d.ParkingLots[i].Name != "") {
        google.maps.event.addListener(categoryItems['search'][count].marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.content = '<div class="bubble">' + (this.pushpinInfo.Name != null ? '<h3>' + this.pushpinInfo.Name + '</h3>' : '') + (this.pushpinInfo.Description != null ? this.pushpinInfo.Description : '') + '</div>';
            infowindow.setPosition(this.centerLatLng);
            infowindow.open(map);
        });
    }
```

---

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(categoryItems['search'][count].marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.content = '<div class="bubble"><h3>' + this.pushpinInfo.Name + '</h3>' + (this.pushpinInfo.ImageUrl != null ? '<img src="' + this.pushpinInfo.ImageUrl + '" alt="' + this.pushpinInfo.Acronym + '" />' : '') + this.pushpinInfo.Description + '</div>';
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
```

---

```
        if (data.d[i].ParkingLots[a].Name != null && data.d[i].ParkingLots[a].Name != "") {
            google.maps.event.addListener(categoryItems[6][i].ParkingLots[a].marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.content = '<div class="bubble">' + (this.pushpinInfo.Name != null ? '<h3>' + this.pushpinInfo.Name + '</h3>' : '') + (this.pushpinInfo.Description != null ? this.pushpinInfo.Description : '') + '</div>';
                infowindow.setPosition(this.centerLatLng);
                infowindow.open(map);
            });
        }
```

---

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(categoryItems[data.d[0].TypeID][i].marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.content = '<div class="bubble"><h3>' + this.pushpinInfo.Name + '</h3>' + (this.pushpinInfo.ImageUrl != null ? '<img src="' + this.pushpinInfo.ImageUrl + '" alt="' + this.pushpinInfo.Name + '" />' : '') + this.pushpinInfo.Description + '</div>';
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
```

Comment: The latest jquery  (version 1.9, beta released Dec 2012) is changed a lot and the older website written with older version may not work well, you can try to use older jquery version to see whether the issue is resolved.

Comment: Ref: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/09/jquery-1-9-rc1-and-migrate-rc1-released/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not related to the jQuery-version, it's the Maps-API-version that breaks it(since 3.10)

You set the content-property of the infoWindows directly, which seems to fail since 3.10.

You may either fix the script(use `setContent()` instead) or specify the API-version:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&sensor=false
```

(but I would suggest to fix it)

Comment: As an aside, and just out of curiosity, where can I find what the current API version is and when there have been updates? I tried to find a version history or something of the like and completely failed.

Comment: On https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en you find in the left navbar the latest versions, including the current release. The changelog you find [**here**](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog) , but the issue isn't listed there as far as I see.